# Is there a list of Just Intonation chords as defined by Fétis, using ratios?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, tuning, musicology, just-intonation

One way of ‘spelling’ chords in just intonation is using ratios - such as 10:12:14:17 (multiplications of the frequency of an implied ‘missing fundamental’). Fétis is quoted in Wikipedia (and here by Andras Hummar) as having defined the spelling above of the diminished seventh chord. I can’t find where this reference is from. Is there a list of tunings as defined by Fétis?

Comment: Who is Fétis?  Which Wikipedia article?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminished_seventh_chord
This article. Fétis was a Belgian music theorist, 1784-1871.

Comment: I’m sorry not to have been clearer earlier, it is chord tunings ‘spelled’ in ratios that I would like to find a list of, rather than just intervals. I am not only interested in chords as defined by Fétis, but any other chords defined in the same way, using ratios - preferably also with the name of the person who first described the chord in this way.

Comment: I understand.  I looked a bit at Fétis's works, and found a reference to the 10:12:14:17 ratios that I think he refers to as a minor ninth chord (I was working somewhat more quickly than I should given the state of my French) despite not including the root (i.e. 8:10:12:14:17).  But he identified the chord almost incidentally in the context of describing the overtone series rather than mentioning overtones in the context of describing chords.  I wanted to look at some of his other works before writing an answer, but I haven't had time.